# Civicrm German Language not displaying even when set to German after upgrade to 5.65.2

Tags: wordpress, language

Salut.
I have all language files and databases in the right place, I can choose German in the language selector, but the menu and everything else stays English (even when I switched to single-language instead of multi-language system, with focus German). Also when I choose the option to prioritize the language from the CMS (Wordpress in German), it still displays in English. No problem before the upgrade to 5.65.2
What can I do? Thank you for any hints.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

---

First message:

---

**Possible solution - will be tested here - :**

- disable in the admin interface all except language EN
- remove the installed language files in /l10n/ and /sql/
- ... (to check what is inside  the MySQL data base...)
- install again using the extension " uplang ".

**here what I have tested so far for the same problem:**

**CIVICRM: Same problem here for new installed**

- DRUPAL 10.1.5.
- CIVICERM 5.66.0
- Language files: Had been installed manually.
- Configuration: "Language is inherited" from DRUPAL setting.

**DRUPAL: All 4 languages working properly:**

- EN DE FR ES
- Based on "Language Switcher" of DRUPAL.
- - (for CIVICRM: Same name. Not yet checked in detail.)

**CIVICRM: Working fine for EN FR ES**

- If DE is selected, then CIVICRM continues to use the last language, e.g. EN FR ES.

**CIVICRM: I installed in addition**

- then afterwards the version "German (Switzerland)".
  There was no corresponding additional checkbox then in the CVCRM admin interface for Localization.

**CIVICRM: I installed uplang . So far no effect.**

- I tried several other possible solutions. So far no success.

---

---

second message - some hours later:

---

---

**The problem has been settled.**

Due to various configuration steps until the final success, the cause of the final success can not be identified reliably.

**The probable success cause is:**

- I enabled "German (Switzerland)"
- and I disabled: the language option just "German"

**Besides this, the following configuration steps were tried, too:**

- Disable, enable both German variants in the list of optional languages.
- Set for CIVICRM the German language to the "contact" language, then revert to the setting "inherit the CMS DRUPAL setting".

**Software problem?**
And I played with other options. But the most probable success cause is:
Setting to "German (Switzerland)".
In both cases, the DRUPAL language switcher sets to   /de/

So DRUPAL only knows 1 option for "de" and CIVICRM knows 2 options. This might be the reason.